# Data not showing on frontend in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, foreach

I fetched data from api and updated the state.But data is not showing on frontend.`Console.log()` is working fine.
`<p>{item.title}</p>;` Not working. What is the problem?

````
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";


const ProductsPage = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const fetchProducts = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setProducts(json);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="products-page">
      {products?.map((item) => {
       console.log(item.title);   // working
        <p>{item.title}</p>;      // Not working
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductsPage; ```
````

Comment: What is the value of `products` using the `useState();` without providing any arguments in it? And what will happen when you call `.map` on that `undefined` object on initial render?

Comment: I Understand the error as the initial value is undefined and map will not work on that. How to deal with this? Even if i use [] as initial value         `<p>{item.title}</p>;` this line not dispaying anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to pass empty array when you define state ie `const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);` or have optional chaining where you map ie `products?.map`

```
import { useEffect, useState  } from "react";



const ProductsPage = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const fetchProducts = () => {
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setProducts(json);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="products-page">
      {products?.map((item) => {
       return <p>{item.title}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

Comment: This only disappeared the error , data is not showing `<p>{item.title}</p>;`

Comment: you need to return the jsx `return  <p>{item.title}</p>;`

Comment: after map you need to return it check my updated code

Comment: Finally returned 